# Problema con validación de expresiones regulares en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente validación en C# para que solo acepte números, pero al momento de hacer pruebas pasa el primer if pero en el segundo se salta la validación y muestra el error a pesar de si estar bien.

```
Validator.AddRule(() => claveNumerica, () =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(claveNumerica) && claveNumerica.Length == 7)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(claveNumerica, @"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"))
                        return RuleResult.Valid();
                }
                return RuleResult.Invalid("La clave numérica es requerida");

        });
```

Me pueden a ayudar por favor y de antemano gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: No recuerdo de memoria el regex, pero me parece extenso para que sean solo numeros, claramente algo hay de sobra ahi

Comment: Estás validando que sea cero o un número que tenga al menos 1 digito, que comience por 1-9. ¿Sí?

Comment: Agrega las entradas de tus pruebas y que esperas en la salida, tambien cual es la salida actual donde consideras que es error

Comment: en si lo que quiero validar es un conjunto de 7 números que estén dentro del rango de 0 a 9 positivos y lo que considero el error es el return RuleResult.Invalid

Answer (score 1):

Trata de usar las siguiente expresión `^[0-9]+$`, recuerda que si el string contiene algún espacio, no va hacer match con el patrón.

De igual forma si estas usando el fluent validation, te recomiendo que lo hagas implementando la clase AbstractValidator, generando tu propia clase que contenga las propiedades que quieres validar, de la siguiente manera.

```
public class MiValidator : AbstractValidator<MiClase>
{   
    public MiValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.claveNumerica)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .Matches("^[0-9]+$")
            .Length(7);
    }
}
```

De esta manera mejoras la semántica, y tienes tu código fuerte mente tipado.

Comment: Gracias me yudo con mi problema